# parse XML in JAVA, when there are Duplicate tags

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to read read values from below xml and am using saxparser for this, but am stuck while reading  tag it appears multiple times and i am unable to read the next row tag, can any one help me....?

Whole data appear in between  tag, and  refers different Tables, and  tage gives the set on records need to be inserted and  refers Column name and value need to be inserted into that particular column .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
<TABLEDATA name="web_order_header" rows="1">
<ROW>
<FIELD name="order_id"> 40403141201067683</FIELD>
<FIELD name="order_date"> Mar 14 , 2012</FIELD>
<FIELD name="company_name">Testing</FIELD>
<FIELD name="company_website"> N/A </FIELD>
<FIELD name="customer_firstname">uni</FIELD>
<FIELD name="customer_lastname">u</FIELD>
<FIELD name="email">aaa@xyz.com</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_contact">uni</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_phone">78784</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_phone_ext">N/A</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_address">ss</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_city">mys</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_state">Kar</FIELD>
<FIELD name="billto_zip">5678945</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_contact">uni</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_phone">78784</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_phone_ext">N/A</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_address">ss</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_city">mys</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_state">Kar</FIELD>
<FIELD name="shipto_zip">5678945</FIELD>
</ROW>
</TABLEDATA>

<TABLEDATA name="web_order_detail" rows="3">
<ROW>
<FIELD name="order_id"> 40403141201067683</FIELD>
<FIELD name="qty">1</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_id">JUS72-28250</FIELD>
<FIELD name="mfr">Justrite Manufacturing Co</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_desc">EcoPolyBlend&amp;trade; Drum Collection Station For Spills</FIELD>
<FIELD name="uom">Each</FIELD>
<FIELD name="price">739.00</FIELD>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<FIELD name="order_id"> 40403141201067683</FIELD>
<FIELD name="qty">1</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_id">COM62-CAS-B51V80-CA1B</FIELD>
<FIELD name="mfr">Compressed Air Systems</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_desc">5HP 80 GAL 15CFM Reciprocating Air Compressor</FIELD>
<FIELD name="uom">Each</FIELD>
<FIELD name="price">1265.33</FIELD>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<FIELD name="order_id"> 40403141201067683</FIELD>
<FIELD name="qty">2</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_id">KIM11-05701</FIELD>
<FIELD name="mfr">Kimberly Clark Corp</FIELD>
<FIELD name="item_desc">Wypall&amp;reg; 12.5&amp;quot; x 13&amp;quot; L40 Q-Fold White Towel</FIELD>
<FIELD name="uom">Case</FIELD>
<FIELD name="price">88.00</FIELD>
</ROW>
</TABLEDATA>
</DATA>
```

This is my JAVA code

```
public void readXml(Document requestDoc,PrintStream out)throws IOException, JDOMException, SQLException, ParseException {
             Document responseDoc = null;


             Element root = requestDoc.getRootElement();

             List tableNameList = root.getChildren("TABLEDATA");

             for(int i=0; i<tableNameList.size(); i++){
                 Element table = (Element) tableNameList.get(i);
                 String tableName = table.getAttribute("name").getValue();
                 int numOfRows = table.getAttribute("rows").getIntValue();
                 System.out.println(tableName+" : tableName---------------------- numOfRows : "+numOfRows);

                    List rowList = root.getChild("TABLEDATA").getChildren("ROW");
                    for(int j=0; j<rowList.size(); j++){
                        Element row = (Element) rowList.get(j);
                        System.out.println("row : "+rowList.size());

                        List fieldList =  root.getChild("TABLEDATA").getChild("ROW").getChildren("FIELD");
                        System.out.println("----------------------");
                        for(int k=0; k<fieldList.size(); k++){
                            Element field = (Element) fieldList.get(k);
                            String fieldName = field.getAttribute("name").getValue();
                            String fieldValue = field.getTextTrim();
                            System.out.println(fieldName+"----------------------"+fieldValue);
                        }
                        System.out.println("----------------------");
                    }


             }
```

Comment: The subject of your Question is misleading as you aren't using SAX at all to parse this XML, you're using DOM.  The `Document` object is a DOM class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your always looking at the first table and the first row. To fix it, use the current elements in the for loops.

Replace

```
List rowList = root.getChild("TABLEDATA").getChildren("ROW");
```

with

```
List rowList = table.getChildren("ROW");
```

and

```
List fieldList =  root.getChild("TABLEDATA").getChild("ROW").getChildren("FIELD");
```

with

```
List fieldList =  row.getChildren("FIELD");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath (XML Path Language) instead of using DOM,
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html